# SaaS Webservice Browser integration: How to secure customer ApiKey and let them embed requests in their webpage?

Tags: web-services, security, saas, api-key

I run a SaaS that has a for-pay webservice-endpoint that returns images.

The endpoint is of this form:  http://[**SaaSWebsite**]/api/[**ApiKey**]/[**RequestDetails**]

Some of my customers wish to integrate the service directly into their website's HTML, so when their user's visit the page, the user's browser accesses my webservice-endpoint directly.

For example, my customer's webpage might have something like:

```
<html>
<body>
Hello User, your important pic is: 
<img src="http://mysaaswebsite.com/api/superSecretApiKey/user-request-details">
<body>
</html>
```

An evil user could extract the `superSecretApiKey` and use my SaaS and my real customer would be charged for their usage.

**How can I allow this without disclosing my customer's ApiKey (which is used for billing) to the end-user?**

I was thinking of using the `referer` HTTP header to limit ApiKey access to my customer's website,  but I think that can still be spoofed using curl or the evil user writing their own request code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to the problem:  **A "Public Key" that has whitelisted RequestDetails.**

in my situation `requestDetails` include a URL, so i will let the user whitelist domains they want their `public-key` to be able to access.